# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I use jest to test my aws lambda function. My test is as follow:

Lambda file index2.ts

```
export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context) => {
const response = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2};
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(response)
};};
```

Test file index2.test.ts

```
import * as lambdaFunc from "../index2";
const lambdalocal = require('lambda-local');
const executeLambda = (event) => {
    return lambdalocal.execute({
        event: event,
        lambdaFunc: lambdaFunc,
        lambdaHandler: "handler",
        callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: true,
        timeoutMs: 300,
        verboseLevel: 1
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    })
        .catch(error => {
            return null;
        });
};

describe("Your first test", function () {
 it("returns success response", async (done) => {
    const response = await executeLambda(lambdaEvent);
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    done();

  });
});
```

I did set Jest time out in jest.setup.js and the test does pickup the configured timeout value

```
jest.setTimeout(10000);
```

I tried several solutions suggested in several posts and yet still have the error "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout". Can someone please point out the problem. I use Node 8.10.0, jest 23.3.14 and lambda-local 1.5.2.
I debugged the test, it went through all the way and called the done() statement.

Comment: perhaps the async callback was not called within the 10000ms timeout specified - if only there was more to the error to point out which async callback isn't being called within that time

Comment: does lambdalocal.execute return a Promise? check `.then(response => return response)`. Unless it is a promise it should fail because you're invoking it as `await executeLambda(lambdaEvent)` but there's nothing to await on since response is not a promise itself. I would make your `executeLambda` function `async` and see what the outcome is.